# Running an async background task in Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Reading the Tornado documentation, it's very clear how to call an async function to return a response:

```
class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
        do_something_with_response(response)
        self.render("template.html")
```

What's lacking is how should a call be made asynchronously to a background task that has no relevance to the current request:

```
class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def _background_task():
        pass  # do lots of background stuff

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        _dont_care = yield self._background_task()
        self.render("template.html")
```

This code would be expected to work, except that it runs synchronously and the request waits on it until it's finished.

What is the *right* way to asynchronously call this task, while immediately returning the current request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: Since Tornado 4.0 (July 2014), the below functionality is available in the [IOLoop.spawn_callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.spawn_callback) method.

Unfortunately it's kind of tricky.  You need to both detach the background task from the current request (so that a failure in the background task doesn't result in a random exception thrown into the request) and ensure that *something* is listening to the background task's result (to log its errors if nothing else).  This means something like this:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.stack_context import run_in_stack_context, NullContext
IOLoop.current().add_future(run_in_stack_context(NullContext(), self._background_task),
                            lambda f: f.result())
```

Something like this will probably be added to tornado itself in the future.

Comment: Hope to see this added eventually. Thanks for the thorough answer, and for your work on tornado :)

Answer (score 9):

**I have a time-consuming task in post request**, maybe more than 30 minutes need, but client required return a result immediately.

First, I used [IOLoop.current().spawn_callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.spawn_callback). It works! but!  If the first request task is running, second request task blocked! Because all tasks are in main event loop when use spawn_callback, so one task is synchronous execution, other tasks blocked.

Last, I use [tornado.concurrent](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html). Example:

```
import datetime
import time

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import tornado.web
from tornado import concurrent

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)


class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        def task(arg):
            for i in range(10):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(arg, i)

        executor.submit(task, datetime.datetime.now())
        self.write('request accepted')


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0')
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

and visit http://127.0.0.1:8000, you can see it's run ok:

```
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 0
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 1
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 2
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 0
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 3
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 1
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 4
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 2
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 5
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 0
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 3
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 6
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 1
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 4
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 7
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 2
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 5
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 8
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 3
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 6
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 0
2017-01-17 22:42:10.983632 9
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 4
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 7
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 1
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 5
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 8
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 2
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 6
2017-01-17 22:42:13.710145 9
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 3
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 7
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 4
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 8
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 5
2017-01-17 22:42:16.694966 9
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 6
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 7
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 8
2017-01-17 22:42:19.790646 9
```

Want to help everyone!

Comment: The reason you were unable to run this concurrently is because `time.sleep` is blocking, as I found out here: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#id2 But if you use a non-blocking function you shouldn't need tornado.concurrent and `spawn_callback` should be sufficient

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using [toro](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/). It provides a relatively simple mechanism for setting up a background queue of tasks.

The following code (put in queue.py for example), starts a simple "worker()" that simply waits until there is something in his queue.  If you call `queue.add(function,async,*args,**kwargs)` this adds an item to the queue which will wake up worker() which then kicks off the task.

I added the async parameter so that this can support background tasks wrapped in @gen.coroutine and those without.

```
import toro,tornado.gen
queue = toro.Queue()
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def add(function,async,*args,**kwargs):
   item = dict(function=function,async=async,args=args,kwargs=kwargs)
   yield queue.put(item)

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def worker():
   while True:
      print("worker() sleeping until I get next item")
      item = yield queue.get()
      print("worker() waking up to process: %s" % item)
      try:
         if item['async']:
            yield item['function'](*item['args'],**item['kwargs'])
         else:
            item['function'](*item['args'],**item['kwargs'])
      except Exception as e:
         print("worker() failed to run item: %s, received exception:\n%s" % (item,e))

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def start():
   yield worker()
```

In your main tornado app:

```
import queue
queue.start()
```

And now you can schedule a back ground task quite simply:

```
def my_func(arg1,somekwarg=None):
   print("in my_func() with %s %s" % (arg1,somekwarg))

queue.add(my_func,False,somearg,somekwarg=someval)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
self._background_task()
```

The `_background_task` coroutine returns a `Future` which is unresolved until the coroutine completes. If you **don't** yield the `Future`, and instead simply execute the next line immediately, then `get()` doesn't wait for `_background_task` to finish.

An interesting detail is that, until `_background_task` finishes, it maintains a reference to `self`. (Don't forget to add `self` as a parameter, by the way.) Your RequestHandler won't be garbage collected until after `_background_task` completes.

Comment: This is proving to be slightly harder than I thought, my task is doing some non-trivial stuff that can't easily be "asynchronized" (posix socket IO). Since its currently blocking the entire IO loop, it's hard to test, but this seems to be the right direction, thanks!

Comment: But if you don't yield / wait for the `Future`, does the method body actually run?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer in 2019!

Start with some slow **non-blocking** code. See: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#id2

```
async def _do_slow_task(self, pk):
    await asyncio.sleep(pk)
    logger.info(f'Finished slow task after {pk} seconds')
```

See here to understand the difference between async and blocking: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html#asynchronous-and-non-blocking-i-o

Then, make your request method a **coroutine** with the `async/await` syntax, which makes it **non-blocking** in order to handle multiple requests in parallel.

```py
async def post(self):
    """Make a few requests with different pks and you should see that
        the numbers logged are in ascending order.
    """
    pk = self.get_query_argument('pk')
    try:
        record = await self.db_queryone(
            f"SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = {int(pk)};"
        )
    except Exception as e:
        self.set_status(400)
        self.write(str(e))
        return
    await self._do_slow_task(pk)
    self.write(f'Received {pk}')
```

Now, modify the method a bit to **run in the background** or

> “fire and forget” a coroutine without waiting for its result

so that the client receives a response right away. See: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#how-to-call-a-coroutine

```py
async def post(self):
    """Make a few requests with different pks and you should see responses
        right away, and eventually log messages with the numbers in
        ascending order.
    """
    pk = self.get_query_argument('pk')
    try:
        record = await self.db_queryone(
            f"SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = {int(pk)};"
        )
    except Exception as e:
        self.set_status(400)
        self.write(str(e))
        return
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self._do_slow_task, pk)
    self.write(f'Received {pk}')
```