# Python Tornado - How to create background process?

Tags: python, tornado

Is it possible to let Python Tornado run some long background process, but concurrently, it is also serving all the handlers?

I have a Tornado Webapp that serves some webpages. But I also have a message queue, and I want Tornado to poll the message queue as a subscriber. Can this be done in Tornado?

I've searched around the user guide, and there seems to be something called a `periodic_call_back` I can use within the ioloop. It sounds like I can use a callback function that reads a message queue. However, is there a way to create a co-routine that never stops?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: em... you can have your producer run in different process and send signal to tornado process right after it produces, then in signal handler, you can insert callback. in this way, things can go async.

Comment: When you say process, do you actually mean a different OS process, or just a function running in the background without blocking the event loop?

Comment: @dano I was thinking a function running in the background, and without blocking the event loop.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, you mean a different script running in the background? I could go that way, but I want to make the process more elegant, as everything is inside Tornado.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082165/running-an-async-background-task-in-tornado) for the right way to run a background task. If you want the task to run infinitely, just put it in a `while True:` loop. Just make sure that when the task waits to consume from the message queue, you do it using a non-blocking call. If you're using a third-party queuing library, you may need to find a `tornado`-friendly version.

Comment: @dano, do you mean before I start the ioloop, use, `IOLoop.spawn_callback()` and the function (which reads the message queue), should not be blocking. Is that right?

Comment: @user1157751 As long as the function which reads the message queue is actually implemented as a proper coroutine (meaning it doesn't make any blocking I/O calls), then yes. You can't just do it with any old function, though.

Comment: @dano Thanks for your help! I'll wrap the function with a coroutine. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: @user1157751 You can't just wrap the function in a coroutine. Whatever library you're using to read from the queue has to actually be implemented using asynchronous I/O. What message queue library are you using?

Comment: @dano I was thinking about PyZMQ for ZeroMQ message queue. If I wrap the read with future, and I yield it, wouldn't that make it async?

Comment: @user1157751 No, it's not quite that simple. There are [instructions on the PyZMQ site](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/eventloop.html) that document how you can make it work with tornado, though.

Comment: @dano Thanks for sharing the instructions! I'm confused why it's not possible to wrap the function with future like this: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py#L43 on line 104.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Read from Zero-MQ:

1. Install Zero-MQ Python Library
2. Install the IOLoop before application.listen()
3. Use an executor (For python2, you can install executor libraries from python3) to execute a message queue listener, which setups tornado to listen to a message queue, and then it will utilize callbacks when it recieves data.

Example (main.py):

```
# Import tornado libraries
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
# Import URL mappings
from url import application
# Import zeroMQ libraries
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
# Import zeroMQ.py functions
from zeroMQ import startListenToMessageQueue
# Import zeroMQ settings
import zeroMQ_settings
# Import our executor
import executors
# Import our db_settings
import db_settings

# main.py is the main access point of the tornado app, to run the application, just run "python main.py"

# What this will do is listen to port 8888, and then we can access the app using
# http://localhost:8888 on any browser, or using python requests library
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Install PyZMQ's IOLoop
    ioloop.install()

    # Set the application to listen to port 8888
    application.listen(8888)

    # Get the current IOLoop
    currentIOLoop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()

    # Execute ZeroMQ Subscriber for our topics
    executors.executor.submit(startListenToMessageQueue(zeroMQ_settings.server_subscriber_ports,
                                                        zeroMQ_settings.server_subscriber_IP,
                                                        zeroMQ_settings.server_subscribe_list))

    # Test if the connection to our database is successful before we start the IOLoop
    db_settings.testForDatabase(db_settings.database)

    # Start the IOLoop
    currentIOLoop.start()
```

Example (zeroMQ.py):

```
# Import our executor
import executors
# Import zeroMQ libraries
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop, zmqstream
# Import db functions to process the message
import db

# zeroMQ.py deals with the communication between a zero message queue

def startListenToMessageQueue(subscribe_ports, subscribe_IP, subscribe_topic):
    # Usage:
    #       This function starts the subscriber for our application that will listen to the
    #       address and ports specified in the zeroMQ_settings.py, it will spawn a callback when we
    #       received anything relevant to our topic.
    # Arguments:
    #       None
    # Return:
    #       None

    # Get zmq context
    context = zmq.Context()

    # Get the context socket
    socket_sub = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

    # Connect to multiple subscriber ports
    for ports in subscribe_ports:
        socket_sub.connect("tcp://"+str(subscribe_IP)+":"+str(ports))

    # Subscribe to our relevant topics
    for topic in subscribe_topic:
        socket_sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topic)

    # Setup ZMQ Stream with our socket
    stream_sub = zmqstream.ZMQStream(socket_sub)

    # When we recieve our data, we will process the data by using a callback
    stream_sub.on_recv(processMessage)

    # Print the Information to Console
    print "Connected to publisher with IP:" + \
          str(subscribe_IP) + ", Port" + str(subscribe_ports) + ", Topic:" + str(subscribe_topic)

def processMessage(message):
    # Usage:
    #       This function processes the data using a callback format. The on_recv will call this function
    #       and populate the message variable with the data that we recieved through the message queue
    # Arguments:
    #       message: a string containing the data that we recieved from the message queue
    # Return:
    #       None

    # Process the message with an executor, and use the addData function in our db to process the message
    executors.executor.submit(db.addData, message)
```

Example (executors.py):

```
# Import futures library
from concurrent import futures

# executors.py will create our threadpools, and this can be shared around different python files
# which will not re-create 10 threadpools when we call it.
# we can a handful of executors for running synchronous tasks

# Create a 10 thread threadpool that we can use to call any synchronous/blocking functions
executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
```

Example (zeroMQ_settings.py):

```
# zeroMQ_settings.py keep the settings for zeroMQ, for example port, IP, and topics that
# we need to subscribe

# Set the Port to 5558
server_subscriber_ports = ["5556", "5558"]

# Set IP to localhost
server_subscriber_IP = "localhost"

# Set Message to Subscribe: metrics.dat
server_subscriber_topic_metrics = "metrics.dat"

# Set Message to Subscribe: test-010
server_subscribe_topics_test_010 = "test-010"

# List of Subscriptions
server_subscribe_list = [server_subscriber_topic_metrics, server_subscribe_topics_test_010]
```

Extra thanks to @dano