# How to launch a background task in tornado, which will not block request handling?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, nonblocking

I'm writing a service which consume a disk space and have to clean it from time to time. Before this moment cleaning was performed in request handling. Unfortunately, in case when there is a big disk space have to be cleaned, it consume a lot of time and service hangs. I tried to rewrite cleaning procedure as tornado's future but confused in way of making a future(or something like this) from generator. There is a simplification of my code below:

```
import tornado
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.process import Subprocess
#from tornado.stack_context import run_in_stack_context, NullContext
from time import time
import random
import json
import asyncio 

class meta_doc(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, methods):
        super().__init__(name, bases, methods)
        cls.storage_size=0

class Documentation_parsing(tornado.web.RequestHandler, metaclass=meta_doc):
    max_storage_size=200
    optimal_storage_size=100
    cleaning=False
    @classmethod
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def _collect_old_folders(cls):
        print('start cleaning')
        for d in subfolders:
            if cls.storage_size<cls.optimal_storage_size:
                break
            delta=random.randint(5, 15)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 3))
            cls.storage_size-=delta
            print('Folder have been deleted. Folder size:', cls.storage_size)
            yield None
        cls.cleaning=False  
        print('finish cleaning')
    @classmethod
    def collect_old_folders(cls):
        if not cls.cleaning:
            cls.cleaning=True
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_future(cls._collect_old_folders, lambda f: f.result())
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        request_id=self.get_body_argument("request_id", default='')
        self.__class__.storage_size+=random.randint(5, 15)
        if self.storage_size>self.max_storage_size:
            self.collect_old_folders()
        self.write(json.dumps({'request_id': request_id, 'storage_size': self.storage_size}))
        print('process request: request_id {0}, storage size {1}'.format(request_id, self.storage_size))

ApplicationSuffixes=[(r'/main_parsing.*', Documentation_parsing)]

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application(ApplicationSuffixes)
    app.listen(9999)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

This code return future assertation error. I looked for another decorator which make a future from generator or corutine, but didn't find. Please help me with this problem.
UPD. I have already tried solution from mentioned question but receive "Cannot import run_in_stack_context". That's why such import is commented in my code

Comment: @asyndrige I tried solution from mentioned question but receive "Cannot import run_in_stack_context"

Comment: I think its because you are using older version of Tornado. Try advice from other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700213/3782382

Answer (score 0):

Solve it:

```
import tornado
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.process import Subprocess
#from tornado.stack_context import run_in_stack_context, NullContext
import time
import random
import json
import asyncio 

class meta_doc(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, methods):
        super().__init__(name, bases, methods)
        cls.storage_size=0

class Documentation_parsing(tornado.web.RequestHandler, metaclass=meta_doc):
    max_storage_size=200
    optimal_storage_size=100
    cleaning=False
    @classmethod
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def _collect_old_folders(cls):
        print('start cleaning')
        while True:
            if cls.storage_size<cls.optimal_storage_size:
                break
            delta=random.randint(5, 15)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 3))
            cls.storage_size-=delta
            print('Folder have been deleted. Folder size:', cls.storage_size)
            yield None
        cls.cleaning=False  
        print('finish cleaning')
    @classmethod
    def collect_old_folders(cls):
        def func(inp):
            print('called', inp)
        if not cls.cleaning:
            cls.cleaning=True
            future=cls._collect_old_folders()
            print(type(future))
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_future(future, func)
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        request_id=self.get_body_argument("request_id", default='')
        self.__class__.storage_size+=random.randint(5, 15)
        if self.storage_size>self.max_storage_size:
            self.collect_old_folders()
        self.write(json.dumps({'request_id': request_id, 'storage_size': self.storage_size}))
        print('process request: request_id {0}, storage size {1}'.format(request_id, self.storage_size))

ApplicationSuffixes=[(r'/main_parsing.*', Documentation_parsing)]

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application(ApplicationSuffixes)
    app.listen(8999)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comments: decorator tornado.gen.coroutine return a function which return a future. So I just need to call method to get future. In 5.0.2 version of Tornado I can add a future directly to IOLoop. The only think is that apart of future I have to pass a function as a second parameter. The function receive Exceptions or result of performance of future.